# Using roles with Realtime Database (firebase)

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I'm trying to write a project using Realtime Database (firebase)  and Angular. Lately I've been trying to learn how to use roles in a project (user, manager, admin, etc.). Did I understand correctly - in the case of using Realtime Database, it is impossible to create roles. Instead, you need to use the rules in the database:

```js
rules: {
   "adminContent": {
       ".read": "auth.token.admin === true",
       ".write": "auth.token.admin === true",
     }
```

Everything was very good until I read:

> Firebase gives you complete control over authentication by allowing you to authenticate users or devices using secure JSON Web Tokens (JWTs). You generate these tokens on your server, pass them back to a client device, and then use them to authenticate via the signInWithCustomToken () method.

What does "your server" mean?  I am using Realtime Database and firebase authentication and this is not enough and I need server?
Maybe there is an easier way to add roles to the Realtime Database, I just haven't found it?

Comment: The page you're referring to with that quote is specifically for creating custom tokens and the instructions on how to do that. It's saying "if you dont want to use firebase auth, you can make tokens on your own server"

Comment: I want to add roles to a project. I read that i cannot add them to Realtime Database, but i need to use the rules for Realtime Database. Here is the expression "auth.token.admin" - the token that is mentioned here is a custom token? Are there other types of tokens for Realtime Database?

Comment: Found - there are 3 types of tokens, I'm afraid that only custom token is suitable for roles, but I don't know yet.